# Configuring android native resources at LaunchTheme and NormalTheme have no visual effects (White screen)

Tags: android, flutter, android-resources

Problem:
Changing/configuring the file launch_background.xml at android module does not have any effect on launching/splash screen **i.e. The white screen at startup continues to show until flutter app draws the first frame.**

I'm following up instructions to customize the splash screen; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JVpFNfnuOZM

However, changes to `<item android:drawable="@android:color/black" />` have no visual effect.

The same goes for the image which does not show (see right bellow)

```
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@mipmap/fist" />
    </item>
```

Notice that this is a brand new project, created by the flutter plugin in Android studio (details below)

Many thanks,

Here is the development environment:

Flutter:

```
% flutter -v doctor
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 2.9.0-1.0.pre.328, on macOS 11.6 20G165 darwin-x64, locale en-GB)
    • Flutter version 2.9.0-1.0.pre.328 at /Users/jorge2antibes/dev/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision d290763941 (4 days ago), 2022-01-11 18:20:14 -0800
    • Engine revision 643b2787f4
    • Dart version 2.16.0 (build 2.16.0-159.0.dev)
    • DevTools version 2.9.2

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/jorge2antibes/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 31.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7281165)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • CocoaPods version 1.10.1

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7281165)
```

Manifest:

```
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Project's build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-all.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

I maintain a package [flutter_native_splash](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash) that will create the splash screen for you automatically and change the default white screen that you are seeing.